# paginate_links() Display current page in query string

Tags: wordpress, query-string, pagination

My custom post type loop pagination is working properly. However, the url I'm getting is like:

```
"my-site.com/courses/page/3/"
```

But what I'm trying to get is:

```
"my-site.com/courses/page/3/?pag=3"
```

so user be abled to set '?pag=2' and redirect to "my-site.com/courses/page/2/?pag=2".
**I have achieve this in index page with '?paged=2' query, but not yet in this one.**

My code:

```
<?php 
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
//$paged = (get_query_var('page')) ? get_query_var('page') : 1; IN INDEX PAGE

$args = array(
            'post_type'         =>'courses',
            'posts_per_page'    => 6,
            'paged'             => $paged,
            'orderby'           => 'title',                  
            'order'             => 'ASC'
        );
$courses = new Wp_Query($args);
if($courses -> have_posts()):
while($courses -> have_posts()): $courses -> the_post();?>

<!-- HTML loop -->

<?php endwhile; ?>

<div class="pagination">
<?php 
echo paginate_links(array(  'total'     => $courses->max_num_pages, 
                            'base'      => add_query_arg('paged','%#%'),
                            'format'    => '?paged=%#%',
                            'current'   => max(1, get_query_var('paged'))
                            //'current'   => max(1, get_query_var('page')) IN INDEX PAGE
                    ));
?>
</div>                  

<?php 
endif; 
wp_reset_postdata();
?>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I used this code ,hope this will help you with minor changes.

```
global $wp_query,
  $wp_query->query_vars['paged'] > 1 ? $current = $wp_query->query_vars['paged'] : $current = 1;

        $pagination = array(
            'base' => @add_query_arg('page','%#%'),
            'format' => '',
            'total' => $wp_query->max_num_pages,
            'current' => $current,
            'show_all' => true,
            'type' => 'list',
            'next_text' => '&raquo;',
            'prev_text' => '&laquo;'
            );
```

Comment: Thank you. I modified 'base' => @add_query_arg('**paged**','%#%'), links work, but url still not displaying the parameter

Comment: In this case 'base' would be '%_%' (Default value)?
The point is that, any way, page links href always have query var, like href="my-site.com/courses/page/2/?paged=2", but Wordpress removes that query var when going to the page